# The Art of Word Shaping

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

## The Art of Word Shaping

Given a binary matrix and a string of letters, replace all 1's in the matrix, moving from top to bottom and from left to right within each row, with the letters of the string. Once the letters have been formed into the shape of the matrix, print the matrix, replacing 0's with spaces. It's probably easier to just give an example or two.

---

Case: *Base case...*

**Input One:**

```
[0,0,1,0,0]
[0,1,0,1,0]
[1,0,0,0,1]
[0,1,0,1,0]
[0,0,1,0,0]

"PPCGPPCG"
```

**Output One:**

```
  P    
 P C  
G   P
 P C 
  G
```

---

Case: *If the input string is longer than the number of ones...*

**Input Two:**

```
[1,0,0]
[0,1,0]
[1,0,1]

lambda
```

**Output Two:**

```
l  
 a 
m b
```

---

Case: *If the input string is shorter than the number of ones...*

**Input Three:**

```
[1,1,1]
[1,0,1]
[1,1,1]

PPCG
```

**Output Three:**

```
PPC
G P
PCG
```

---

## Available Assumptions

- You may assume the input string is never empty.
- You may assume the matrix will never be empty.
- You may not assume that the binary matrix will never be all zeros.

## Rules

- If the string is shorter than the number of ones, repeat the string; all ones must be replaced.
- If the string is longer than the number of ones, only use what is needed.
- You may use True/False in place of integers/bits for the input.
- Trailing spaces ARE REQUIRED, all zeros must be **replaced** with spaces.
- A single trailing newline is acceptable.
- This is code-golf, lowest byte count wins.

Comment: Does the matrix have to be input as an array or can I use a multiline-string?

Comment: @Titus that's fine, Martin Ender already did.

Comment: The base case is not left to right. Do you mean top to bottom, then left to right?

Comment: If the matrix is, for example, a 2x2 grid of zeroes, should we output a single space or a 2x2 grid of spaces?

Comment: @pieman2201 cleared up test case #4 to be better.

Comment: @BlueEyedBeast good call, made an edit to make it more clear on pieman's question and forgot that it wasn't even a valid input scenario.

Comment: Must the output contain spaces or can it contain characters which are rendered as spaces? For example, in Python `print '\x00'` looks the same as `print ' '`

Comment: @wnnmaw ASCII character code 32 is the only usable thing ;).

Comment: `Trailing spaces ARE REQUIRED, all zeros must be replaced with spaces.` um, can we have extra trailing spaces?

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon no. That's what "all zeros must be replaced with spaces" was covering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
yz:)1Gg!(c!
```

Inputs are a numeric matrix (with `;` as row separator) and a string.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eXo6KTFHZyEoYyE&input=WzAsMCwxLDAsMDsgMCwxLDAsMSwwOyAxLDAsMCwwLDE7IDAsMSwwLDEsMDsgMCwwLDEsMCwwXQonUFBDR1BQQ0cn) Or verify test cases: [**1**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eXo6KTFHZyEoYyE&input=WzAsMCwxLDAsMDsgMCwxLDAsMSwwOyAxLDAsMCwwLDE7IDAsMSwwLDEsMDsgMCwwLDEsMCwwXQonUFBDR1BQQ0cn), [**2**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eXo6KTFHZyEoYyE&input=WzEsMCwwOyAwLDEsMDsgMSwwLDFdCidsYW1iZGEnCgo), [**3**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eXo6KTFHZyEoYyE&input=WzEsMSwxOyAxLDAsMTsgMSwxLDFdCidQUENHJwoK).

```
y       % Take the two inputs implicitly. Duplicate the first
        % STACK: [1,0,0; 0,1,0; 1,0,1], 'lambda', [1,0,0; 0,1,0; 1,0,1]
z       % Number of nonzeros
        % STACK: [1,0,0; 0,1,0; 1,0,1], 'lambda', 4
:       % Range
        % STACK: [1,0,0; 0,1,0; 1,0,1], 'lambda', [1 2 3 4]
)       % Reference indexing (select values)
        % STACK: [1,0,0; 0,1,0; 1,0,1], 'lamb'
1Gg     % Push first input as a logical matrix; will be used as index
        % STACK: [1,0,0; 0,1,0; 1,0,1], 'lamb', [1,0,0; 0,1,0; 1,0,1]
!       % Transpose. This is necessary because MATL uses column-major order
        % (down, then accross)
(       % Assignment indexing (fill with values). Since the original matrix
        % is numeric, the new values are introduced as their ASCII codes
        % STACK: [108, 0, 109; 0, 97, 0; 1, 0, 98]
c       % Convert to char
        % STACK: ['l m'; ' a '; '  b']
!       % Transpose back. Implicitly display
        % STACK: ['l  '; ' a '; 'm b']
```

Comment: MATL basically redefines how I've always seen collections...

Comment: @carusocomputing Like in Matlab, the main data type is "rectangular" arrays: matrices or their n-dimensional analogues. They can contain numbers, chars or Boolean values. There are also cell arrays, that can contain arbitrary things, like Python's lists

Comment: Best answer selected after 2 weeks open.

Answer (score 8):

## Vim, <s>44</s> 42 bytes

```
qqy$P0xjf1"_xP{@qq@q:s/0/ /g^M:s/,/^V^M/g^M{D
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [@DjMcMoylex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31716/drmcmoylex)!

Here, the `^M` is a literal newline, and the `^V` is <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd>

Takes the input in this format:

```
PPCG
00100,01010,10001,01010,00100
```

**Disclaimer:** If the string is longer than ~40 chars long, your computer might run out of ram.

Explanation:

```
qq             @qq@q                            # Start recording a recursive macro.
  y$P0x                                         # Duplicate the string and cut out the first character
       jf1"_xP{                                 # Find the first 1, and replace it with the cut character from the string.
                                                # Now we have replaced all the 1's with their respective character, but we still have the array in the original format, and we have the string massivly duplicated at the first line, so we need to clean it up:
                    :s/0/ /g^M                  # Replace all 0's with a space
                              :s/,/^V^M/g^M     # Replace all ,'s with a newline. The ^V acts like a backslash, it escapes the newline so that the command isn't run too soon
                                           {D   # Delete the first line
```

Here's a gif of me "running" the "program":

[image: Me typing the keys]

Comment: Hahaha, love the disclaimer.

Comment: You could use `{` in place of `gg` to take a couple off.

Comment: Ok, the gif is really neat, but do you think you could include it via link only? It lags my chrome every time I try to scroll past :(

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>67</s> <s>53</s> <s>50</s> 49 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions
Saved 1 more thanks to @Neil

```
(a,b,i)=>a.replace(/./g,c=>+c?b[++i]||b[i=0]:' ')
```

```js
f=
(a,b,i)=>a.replace(/./g,c=>+c?b[++i]||b[i=0]:' ')

G=_=>h.innerHTML = f(`00100
01010
10001
01010
00100`,z.value)
h.innerHTML = G()
```

```html
<input id=z oninput="G()" value="PPCG"></input>
<pre id=h>
```

Old code before I knew that string matrices are a valid input format:

```
(a,b)=>a.map(c=>c.map(d=>d?b[i++%b.length]:' ').join``,i=0).join`
`
```

```js
f=
(a,b)=>a.map(c=>c.map(d=>d?b[i++%b.length]:' ').join``,i=0).join`
`

G=_=>h.innerHTML = f([[0,0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,0]],z.value)
h.innerHTML = G()
```

```html
<input id=z oninput="G()" value="PPCG"></input>
<pre id=h>
```

Comment: I'd suggest `c=>' '[c]||b[i++%b.length]`, but sadly it's a byte longer...

Comment: However, there's another way to save 3 bytes: `(a,b,i)=>a.replace(/\d/g,c=>+c?b[++i]||b[i=0]:' ')`

Comment: I think that will start at the second character of the string. A snippet update would be nice.

Comment: @Titus At first, `i` is `undefined`, so `++i` returns `NaN`. Since `b` has no `NaN` property, `b[++i]` returns `undefined`, and the `||` operator runs its right-side argument, setting `i` to `0` and returning the first char in `b`.

Comment: @ETHproductions Now that´s index magic. I keep forgetting about `NaN`. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you testing for `\d`? Surely `.` suffices, since you only have to deal with `0`s and `1`s (`.` doesn't match newlines).

Answer (score 6):

### [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>41</s> 33 bytes

```
0

+1`(.)(.*)(\D+)1
$2$1$3$1
A1`
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=MAogCisxYCguKSguKikoXEQrKTEKJDIkMSQzJDEKQTFg&input=UFBDRwowMDEwMAowMTAxMAoxMDAwMQowMTAxMAowMDEwMA)

The input string is given on the first row of the input, followed by the matrix. Since Retina has no concept of lists (or really anything except strings), there are no separators in the binary matrix except for linefeeds to separate rows.

#### Explanation

```
0
```

Turns zeros into spaces.

```
+1`(.)(.*)(\D+)1
$2$1$3$1
```

Repeatedly replace the first `1` with the first character of the input string while also rotating that character to the end of the input string. This takes care cases where there are more `1`s than characters in the input string.

```
A1`
```

Discard the first line, i.e. the input string.

Comment: `(.)(.*)` - Teehee...

Answer (score 5):

### Perl, 40 bytes

36 bytes of code + `-i -p` flags.

```pl
@F=$^I=~/./g;s/1/$F[$i++%@F]/g;y;0;
```

(note the final space and the lack of final newline).

To run it, write the input string after `-i` flag, and supply the matrix in the input :

```
perl -iPPCGPPCG -pe '@F=$^I=~/./g;s/1/$F[$i++%@F]/g;y;0; ' <<< "00100
01010
10001
01010
00100"
```

If your Perl is a bit old, you might need to add a final semicolon (after the space).

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>114</s> 71 bytes

Turns out I was re-inventing the wheel, a simple double replace on a multiline string works quite well.  The string has the additional benefit of being able to count zeros directly rather than having to do the really ugly `s*len(L)*len(L[0])` for a nested list

```
lambda S,s:S.replace("0"," ").replace("1","{}").format(*s*S.count('0'))
```

Old solution:

```
lambda s,L:"\n".join(["".join(map(lambda n:chr(n+32),l)).replace("!","{}")for l in L]).format(*s*len(L)*len(L[0]))
```

First we convert everything + 32 with `chr` (all zeros become spaces), then we replace all of the `!` with `{}` to allow using the `format` function.

<s>If `NULL` can be counted as a space</s> If I decide to cheat and use `NULL` instead of space, I can skip the addition of 32 to save 12 bytes. (`print` displays `'\x00'` as a space)

```
lambda s,L:"\n".join(["".join(map(chr,l)).replace('\x01','{}')for l in L]).format(*s*len(L)*len(L[0]))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be shorter to use the NULLs, and replace them with space at the end?

Comment: @nedla2004, How do you suggest I do that? Just adding a `.replace('\x00',' ')` on the end adds 20 bytes

Comment: But then I think you could get rid of this: map(lambda n:chr(n+32),l)

Comment: The second solution works with NULLs the whole time, which saves me 12 bytes, swapping to spaces at the end will cost me more than that

Comment: I thought you could remove more than you actually can.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>110</s> <s>91</s> <s>97</s> <s>88</s> <s>82</s> <s>81</s> <s>80</s> 75 bytes

saved 6 bytes thanks to @user59178

```
while(""<$c=$argv[1][$i++])echo$c<1?$c?:" ":($s=$argv[2])[$k++%strlen($s)];
```

Run with `-r`. Expects matrix as multiline string in first argument, string in second argument.

Comment: An 80 byte version based on your 82 bytes version: `foreach(str_split($argv[1])as$c)echo$c<1?$c?:" ":($s=$argv[2])[$k++%strlen($s)];` I swapped the order of the two ternaries and thus dropped the brackets from the second by using `<1` rather than `>0`

Comment: you could save 4 bytes by using `for(;""!=$c=$argv[1][$i++];)` instead of the `foreach(...)`

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 18 bytes

```
{(⍴⍺)⍴X\⍵⍴⍨+/X←,⍺}
```

This is a function that takes a boolean matrix as its left argument and a string as its right argument.

```
      (↑(1 0 0)(0 1 0)(1 0 1)) {(⍴⍺)⍴X\⍵⍴⍨+/X←,⍺}'lambda'
l  
 a 
m b
```

Explanation:

APL has a built-in that does something like this, `\` (expand). However, it only works on vectors, and it requires each character to be actually used.

- `X←,⍺`: flatten the matrix and store the result in X.
- `⍵⍴⍨+/X`: reshape the character vector so that it has the required amount of elements (this also takes care of lengthening the string by repeating characters if necessary).
- `X\`: take one of the characters for each `1` and a space for each `0` in `X`.
- `(⍴⍺)⍴`: reshape the result so that it has the shape of the original matrix.

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell v2+, 70 bytes

```
param($a,$b)$b|%{-join($_|%{if($_){$a[$n++];$n%=$a.length}else{' '}})}
```

Takes input word as `$a` and the matrix as an array-of-arrays as `$b` (see examples below). Loops through `$b`, then loops through the elements of each row `$_|%{...}`. Inner loop is an `if`/`else` condition, where we either output `$a[$n++]` and take mod-equal to the length of the string, or output a space `' '`. Those are `-join`ed together back into a string. Each of the strings is left on the pipeline, and implicit output with newlines between happens via `Write-Output` at program completion.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\the-art-of-word-shaping.ps1 'PPCGPPCG' @(@(0,0,1,0,0),@(0,1,0,1,0),@(1,0,0,0,1),@(0,1,0,1,0),@(0,0,1,0,0))
  P  
 P C 
G   P
 P C 
  G  

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\the-art-of-word-shaping.ps1 'lambda' @(@(1,0,0),@(0,1,0),@(1,0,1))
l  
 a 
m b

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\the-art-of-word-shaping.ps1 'PPCG' @(@(1,1,1),@(1,0,1),@(1,1,1))
PPC
G P
PCG
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3, 104 (or 83) Bytes

```
import itertools as i
def f(s,L):s=i.cycle(s);return'\n'.join(' '.join(next(s)*e for e in l)for l in L)
```

There is shorter option (83 Bytes), but it will fail if string is more than 999 times shorter than needed:

```
def f(s,L):s=list(s)*999;return'\n'.join(' '.join(s.pop(0)*e for e in l)for l in L)
```

Comment: Second solution doesn't work for me, because you can't call `next` on a list. If you do `s=iter(list(s)*999)` it does (89 bytes)

Comment: @L3viathan sorry, I meant it to be `s.pop(0)`. Seems that I copied wrong version, fixed that.

Comment: `s[i++%s.length()]` is a good methodology, though I don't know python.

Comment: It would be cool, but there is no such thing as `i++` in Python

Answer (score 2):

## Groovy, 63

```
{a,b->i=0;a.replaceAll("1",{b[i++%b.size()]}).replace("0"," ")}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>10</s> 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

+1 byte to work around a weird bug with Japt's `-m`ap flag that I've never come across before.

```
®®?VgT°:SÃq
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=rq4/VmdUsDpTw3E&input=WwpbMCwwLDEsMCwwXQpbMCwxLDAsMSwwXQpbMSwwLDAsMCwxXQpbMCwxLDAsMSwwXQpbMCwwLDEsMCwwXQpdCiJQUENHIg)

```
®®?VgT°:SÃq     :Implicit input of 2D boolean array U & string V
®               :Map
 ®              :  Map
  ?             :    If truthy (i.e., 1)
   Vg           :      Get the character in V at index
     T°         :      T (initially 0) postfix incremented
       :        :    Else
        S       :      Space
         Ã      :  End map
          q     :  Join
                :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Comment: For [Test Case 3](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW1S&code=rj9WZ1SwOlPDcQ&input=WwpbMSwxLDFdClsxLDAsMV0KWzEsMSwxXQpdCiJQUENHIg) the last line should be "PCG" not "PPC". After some debugging, my best guess is that Japt is caching the output of individual lines, so when it sees line three is `[1,1,1]` it reuses the line 1 output even though the state has changed.

Comment: Woah, @KamilDrakari, you're right! I've never come across that before, have you? I've tested it in all 3 versions available in my interpreter _and_ on TIO and the results are the same across the board. Will need to dive into the Japt source code to figure out why but, in the meantime, the easy fix is to ditch the `-m` flag and add another `®` at the start of the programme.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
jms?R@z~hZ\
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jms%3FR%40z~hZ%5C%20&input=%5B%5B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%20%5B0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D%2C%20%5B0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%5D%2C%20%5B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%5D%5D%0APPCGPPCG&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
jms?R@z~hZ\ dQ   implicit d and Q at the end
                 I use the variable Z, which is initialized with 0 by default
 m           Q   map each line d of the Q (input matrix) to:
   ?R       d       map each number d of the line either to
     @z~hZ             input[Z++] (increase Z, but lookup in input string with old value)
          \            or space
  s                 join chars to a string
j                print each string on a separate line
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 152 bytes

```
(defun m(g w)(let((a 0))(loop for r in g do(loop for e in r do(format t"~[ ~;~c~]"e(char w a))(if(= e 1)(setf a(mod(1+ a)(length w)))))(format t"~%"))))
```

Usage:

```
* (m (list (list 1 0 1)
           (list 0 1 0)
           (list 1 0 1)) "ppcg")
p p
 c 
g p
```

This function loops through each element of each row of the grid. The `format` control string either prints a space if the element is a 0 or consumes the character argument if the element is 1. A newline gets printed after every row of the grid. If the string is too short, it repeats from the beginning; if it's too long, only the appropriate part gets outputted.

Answer (score 1):

### ES6, 78 bytes

```
  (a,b,x=0)=>(b.map(r=>r.map(i=>i?a[x++%a.length]:' ')+'\n')+'').replace(/,/g,'')
```

I tried

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <strike>237</strike> 233 Bytes

*Edit: saved 4 Bytes thanks to Mukul Kumar*

Golfed:

```
String T(int[][]m,String b){int l=m.length,a=0;String o="";for(int i=0;i<l;i++){for(int j=0;j<l;j++){if(m[i][j]==1&&a<b.length()){o+=Character.toString(b.toCharArray()[a]);a++;if(a== b.length()-1)a=0;}else o+=" ";}o+="\n";}return o;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public String T(int[][] m, String b) {
    int l = m.length,a=0;
    String o = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {
            if(m[i][j] == 1 && a < b.length())
            {
                o += Character.toString(b.toCharArray()[a]);
                a++;
                
                if(a == b.length() - 1)
                    a = 0;
            }
            else
             o += " ";
        }
        o += "\n";
    }
    return o;
}
```

Testing:

```
  int[][] matrix = new int[][]
  {{ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
  { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },{ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },};
  TheArtOfWordShaping taows = new TheArtOfWordShaping();
  System.out.println(taows.T(matrix, "PPCGPPCG"));
    
  matrix = new int[][] {{1,0,0}, {0,1,0}, {1,0, 1}};
  taows = new TheArtOfWordShaping();
  System.out.println(taows.T(matrix, "lamda"));
    
  matrix = new int[][] {{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,1, 1}};
  taows = new TheArtOfWordShaping();
  System.out.println(taows.T(matrix, "PPCG"));

  P  
 P C 
G   P
 P C 
  P  

l  
 a 
m d

PPC
P P
CPP
```

Comment: You can declare all int in one line.....

Answer (score 1):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 18 bytes

17 bytes of code, +1 for `-l` flag.

```
Yb{a?y@++vs}MMa^s
```

Takes the array as the first command-line argument like this: `100 010 101` (needs to be quoted in shells) and the string as the second command-line argument. [Try it online!](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=WWJ7YT95QCsrdnN9TU1hXnM&input=&args=LWw+MDAxMDAgMDEwMTAgMTAwMDEgMDEwMTAgMDAxMDA+SmFiYmVyd29ja3k)

#### Explanation

```
                   a and b are cmdline args, s is space, v is -1
Yb                 Yank b into global variable y
              a^s  Split a on space into list of rows
  {        }MM     Map this function to the items of the items of a (i.e. each character):
   a               Function argument
    ?              Ternary operator (truthy if 1, falsey if 0)
       ++v         If truthy, increment v...
     y@            ... and use it to index into y (cyclically)
                   I.e.: each time we hit a 1, replace it with the next character of y
          s        If falsey, space
                   The result is a list of lists of characters; -l concats sublists and
                   newline-separates the main list
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 12 bytes

```
.FdRIKQoQl%@
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.FdRIKQoQl%25%40&input=PPCG%0A%5B%5B1%2C1%2C1%5D%2C%5B1%2C0%2C1%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%5D%5D)

Outputs a matrix of characters

Or 9 bytes, noncompetitive.

```
.FdRIKQo@
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.FdRIKQo%40&input=PPCG%0A%5B%5B1%2C1%2C1%5D%2C%5B1%2C0%2C1%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%5D%5D)

- Add wrapping on indexables where the index asked for is bigger than the length of the indexable.
  ​
  .F        - deep_for(input)
      I     -  if ^:
        Qo@ -   Q[o++]
    dR      -  else " "

Even more noncompetitive, 8 bytes

```
.FIQo@(P
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.FIQo%40%28P&input=PPCG%0A%5B%5B1%2C1%2C1%5D%2C%5B1%2C0%2C1%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%5D%5D)

- `print_grid` now aligns empty strings properly
- `deep_for` now does type-guessing on falsies of a different type to the truthies

​

```
.F    (  -  deep_for(input)
 I       -   if ^:
  Qo@    -    input[o++]
       P - pretty_print(^)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java,122 bytes

```
String g(int[][]a,char[]b){String r="";int e=0;for(int[]c:a){for(int d:c){r+=d==0?' ':b[e++%b.length];}r+='\n';}return r;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 18 bytes

```
({' '&,)~$$,*+/\@,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NarVFdTVdDTrVFR0tLT1Yxx0/mtylaQWl9jqKaQmZ@Q7pCko6SkZWOvFG3FxqQcEOLuDsLoCSAnIKAMuAwNDAyBpCIRcQJaBIZQNEdf8DwA)

- `,*+/\@,` Flatten the matrix, then multiply the flatten by the scan sum of the flatten.
- `({' '&,)~` Prepend a space to the replacement chars, and the index into that using the result of the previous step.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
SƶDêþIÞðš‡
```

Inputs in the order \$matrix, string\$, where the \$matrix\$ is a multi-line string. Outputs the result as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@Ng2l8OrDu/zPDzv8IajCx81LPz/X0lJydDQkMvQAIgNDYE8roAAZ3cA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpSbKWgpFOZ8KhhmdLh/Uo6OlxKjsklpYk5CvmlJUBpiGzo/@Bj21wOrzq8L@LwvMMbji581LDwv61SQFFqSUmlbkFRZl5JagpUh5KOl86hbfb/o6OVDAwMDQxi8oCkIZACsg0M4TywnJKOUkCAszsIK8XqKEQrwdSDVBsCZXMSc5NSEqFyhoZgYSBhaAjVqRQbCwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
S          # Split the first (implicit) multi-line string to a list of characters
 ƶ         # Multiply each by its 1-based index (the 0s and "\n" remain unchanged, only 
           # the 1s are changed to their 1-based index)
  D        # Duplicate this list
   ê       # Remove all 0s except for a leading one, by using a sorted-uniquify
    þ      # Remove the newline, by only keeping numbers
     I     # Push the second input-string
      Þ    # Cycle its characters indefintely
       ðš  # Prepend a leading space " "
         ‡ # Transliterate the 0s and 1-based indices with these characters
           # (after which the resulting list of characters is output implicitly)
```

With an actual matrix as I/O, it would have been 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) instead by adding a trailing `¹gä`: [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@Ng2l8OrDu/zPDzv8IajCx81LDy0M/3wkv//o6MNdYAwVgdIG0BpED@WKyDA2R0A) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpSbKWgZF@Z8KhhmdLh/Ur2SgqJeSlAER0uJcfkktLEHIX80hKgMqAqncqE0EMr/wcf2@ZyeNXhfRGH5x3ecHTho4aFh9alH17y31YpoCi1pKRSt6AoM68kNQWqUUnH69BunUPb7P9HA4GBjoGOIRAbxOpEQ1iGYDZYDMRDE0eoj9VRCghwdgdhpVgdBaBZKOZAzTAEqctJzE1KSYSrMgSbagg1HcKHmqYUGwsA) (note that the `S` also implicitly flattens, although an actual flatten `˜` could be used here as well).

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 10 bytes

```
$¨Svv¨i?ðṠ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiJMKoU3Z2wqhpP8Ow4bmgIiwiIiwiW1sxLCAwLCAwXSwgWzAsIDEsIDBdLCBbMSwgMCwgMV1dXG5cImxhbWJkYVwiIl0=)

First time I've used `¨S` in an answer I think. Takes matrix then string

### Explained

```
$¨Svv¨i?ðṠ
$          # Push matrix then string to the stack
 ¨S        # and set the input source to the characters of the string. This quite literally overrides argv.
   vv      # to each item in the matrix:
     ¨i    #   if the item is 1:
       ?   #     take input (which will be next character of string)
        ð  #   else: space
         Ṡ # sums of items
           # j flag joins on newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
‛ %İṠ⁋$%
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigJsgJcSw4bmg4oGLJCUiLCIiLCJbWzAsIDAsIDEsIDAsIDBdLCBbMCwgMSwgMCwgMSwgMF0sIFsxLCAwLCAwLCAwLCAxXSwgWzAsIDEsIDAsIDEsIDBdLCBbMCwgMCwgMSwgMCwgMF1dXG5bXCJQXCIsXCJQXCIsXCJDXCIsXCJHXCJdIl0=)

```
   İ     # Index into...
‛ %      # " %"
    Ṡ⁋   # Join each into a string, join by newlines
      $% # Replace %s with corresponding elements of the input
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 76 bytes

```
""<>(s=#2;f:=(s=RotateLeft[s];Last[s]);Map[If[#1,f," "]&,#,{2}]~Riffle~"\n")&
```

Unnamed function of two arguments, the first of which (`#`) is an array of `True`s and `False`s, and the second of which (`s`) is a list of characters. The helper function

```
f:=(s=RotateLeft[s];Last[s])
```

is defined, which puts the moves the first character of `s` to the end and then returns that just-moved character. Calling `f` several times will cyclically return the characters of `s` in order.

The core function is

```
Map[If[#1,f," "]&,#,{2}]
```

which calls `f` on every `True` value in the input array and returns a space on every false input. (The `{2}` tells `Map` to work on elements of the array's component lists, rather than those lists themselves.)

Those 60 bytes return an array of characters-of-`s` and spaces. The wrapper

```
    ""<>(...~Riffle~"\n")&
```

puts newlines between each of that array's lists and then concatenates everything.

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 61 bytes

```c++
for(auto&i:m){for(int&j:i)cout<<(j?s[k++%l]:' ');cout<<'\n';}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 52 bytes

```ruby
->a,s{i=-1
a.gsub(/(0)|1/){$1?" ":s[(i+=1)%s.size]}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3TXTtEnWKqzNtdQ25EvXSi0uTNPQ1DDRrDPU1q1UM7ZUUlKyKozUytW0NNVWL9Yozq1Jja2uheiMKSkuKFdyilQwMDA0MuICEoQEXkGVgCGWDxZV0FJQCApzdQVgplosLpAlCgrQaGhoCtQCxoSFMoVIsxPwFCyA0AA)