# Make a Word Art

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

> *No, not that thing in powerpoint*

You will be given a string, and a 2D array of boolean values. The 2D array will represent a picture.

You will be creating art out of it.

Let me show you how.

## The steps to art

First, you create a square which fits the 2d array, with the string.

Like if the string is 'PPCG', and the picture is 4x3, the square should be like this.

```
PPCG
PCGP
CGPP
GPPC
```

Now in the square, erase all characters which the corresponding boolean is 0, or the corresponding boolean doesn't exist.

Let me show you. If the 2D array is

```
1001
0110
1001
```

And the square is same to the above (above this one), the result should be like:

```
P  G
 CG 
C  P
```

Now output the result.

## Test data is not made yet. Will add ASAP.

## Rules

- General [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply, including loopholes.

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99749/the-art-of-word-shaping?rq=1) I'm sure there was one that created the squares like above too but I can't find it.

Comment: It would help if you use 'ABCD' or something( with non-repeating chars) instead of 'PPCG' in the example... The two 'P's are really confusing to get a clear picture...

Comment: If the string is `ABC` can the input array be `[[1,0],[1,0],[1,0]]` or must the inner arrays be 3 in length?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder The array size isn't determined by the string. In fact the square is determined by the array size.

Comment: @SIGSEGV So is it guaranteed the array will be non-empty and not larger than the string?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder The square must expand as the array does.

Comment: I mean the input array, If the input string is `2` in length is it guaranteed the input array will be at most `2 x 2`?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder no.

Comment: @SIGSEGV So what happens in the case of the string `AB` and array `[[1,1,1][1,1,1][1,1,1]]`?

Comment: May we take the boolean array as a String instead (`10100101` instead of `[[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1]]`?

Comment: And I honestly think it would be more interesting if one should not expand the square if the array is larger, and it would guaranteed that the length of the array is the same as the String's length.

Comment: Does the "direction" we shift the characters to create the square matter? For example, given `PPCG`, could the square be `PPCG,GPPC,CGPP,PCGP`?

Comment: `Test data is not made yet. Will add ASAP.` -> why didn't you just Sandbox this until you had test data?

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 168 bytes

```c#
s=>a=>{var r=new string[a.Length];for(int i=0,j;i<a.Length;++i)for(j=0;j<a[i].Length;++j)r[i]+=a[i][j]>48?(s.Substring(i,s.Length-i)+s.Substring(0,i))[j]:' ';return r;}
```

Works for the example in the question, not entirely sure how it will hold up against future test cases as the spec isn't fully clear.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHLasMwELz7KwZfImHH2NBDqRP3EGihpBCaQw@OD6qjpDKJBJKSUoK/3ZXtPGk7B2m1O7MvlWa4VVI1TblhxmDmHTw4GMusKLFXYolXJiShnbsPtph/G8u30dNOliNjtZDr8A9fXoQ4WVmGFcYwGGdg7jinuiRtsWca2vEk/zpJWTTlcm0/i/SGuVIaREgL4ehxiCp11ggndoogEPRGcVZVrSJF1dJzUVwpqt@KFtqxEIw7dl4VyHB3j0cQE813H32bRLhZj5kwhKAIcB12HQpKW/EDBhik3k0hze1OS@jLiPUV47jZiZJGbXj0roXlUyE56XNHL8p9kb@QfogV8WezybNPidtgXuAAP4njxEX8OEni9u7eqCml/5d442zZVaB9R7VXN80P)

Comment: Can't `Substring(0, i)` be `Substring(0,i)`?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Yeah, just me forgetting to remove all spaces, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 74 bytes

```
(z=Characters@#;Grid[Table[RotateLeft[z,i],{i,0,Length@#2-1}]#2/.0->" "])&
```

**input**

> ["PPCG", {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}}]

works for test case.will update if things get "clearer"...

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>95</s> <s>79</s> 74 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @Mr.Xcoder*

```python
lambda s,b,e=enumerate:[[b*(2*s)[k+i]or' 'for k,b in e(v)]for i,v in e(b)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYgxC8IwEEb/ym1J6g2tbkInB9fu5w0JXjDUJiWNBX99jIg8eHzvW9/lkeKp@vFWn3ZxdwsbOpRR4muRbIuciVynj91maD4ETlmB8inDjA5CBNG74W8H3H/tDNc1h1i012qaLleFRAP2jYGRmht9W/@Pjakf)

Comment: Your function is not recursive, why did you add `f=`?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder thanks for noticing